# During file creation how does the linux kernel find an unused inode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does it go through all inodes until it encounters the first unused inode?
or it has some mechanism for a quick look up of unused inode?
Is there a general standard for doing this or its just implementation specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implementation specific, and there is no standard. Each filesystem (`xfs`, `ext3/4` etc) has its own implementation for allocating a new inode.

Couple of examples:

- `xfs` maintains a [Free inode btree](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XFS#Free_inode_btree) that tracks free inodes.
- `ext4` has a specific [Block and Inode Allocation Policy](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Block_and_Inode_Allocation_Policy) where the data is maintained across multiple block groups, and each block group has its own free inode table. A new inode is allocated according to some block policies.

Comment: Adding for ext4 an inode_bitmap for quicker search. BTW… some note regarding the most common tmpfs would be much appreciated. :-)